# Is it correct to transform $ \lim_{r\to+\infty}\int_{B(0,r)}\frac{1}{1+x^2+|y|}dx\,dy$ into $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\frac{1}{1+x^2+|y|}dx\,dy$?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals

I just wanted to ask if the provided solution to the following integral is correct.

> Prove that
> $$
> \lim_{r\to+\infty}\int_{B(0,r)}\frac{1}{1+x^2+|y|}dx\,dy=\infty
> $$

**Solution**

The above integral equals

$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\frac{1}{1+x^2+|y|}dx\,dy
$$

Integrating first in $x$ and then in $y$, one gets

$$
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\frac{1}{1+x^2+|y|}dx\,dy &=
4\int_0^{+\infty}\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{1}{1+x^2+y}dx\,dy \\[8pt]
&=2\pi\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+y}}dy \\[4pt]
&=\infty
\end{align}$$

More specifically, I wanted to ask if transforming the limit in the exercise into the integral over the whole $\mathbb{R}^2$ is correct.

Comment: Since this is a question in Calculus it requires justification. ( Measure theory makes it immediate).